# jQuery to allocate text to videos or images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It is quite easy to get a video out from a list and bring it up in a html file with jQuery. Now I'd like to allocate some different text to each video. one way would be to write for each text one html file placed through a style sheet. but how could I read my texts out from one file with allocated lines to each video/image?

textfile:

here some text to video1 
some other text to video2 
...

```js
$(function() {
  $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
    $("#videoarea").attr({
      "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
      "autoplay": "autoplay"
    });
  });

  $("#videoarea").attr({
    "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src=""></video>
<ul id="playlist">
  <li movieurl="jembe_3.ogv" >Video 1</li>
  <li movieurl="jembe_4.ogv" >Video 2</li>
  <li movieurl="jembe_5.ogv" >Video 3</li>
  <li movieurl="jembe_6.ogv" >Video 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% understanding your question - are you wanting to store text based information which is "attached" to your videos? I.e. if a video is selected, the text which is attached to that video gets displayed?

Comment: I'd like to store my text in a textfile. one paragraph for one video. If the Video 1 appears the paragraph one should also pop up on a defined place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data attribute:

```
<body>
<video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src=""></video>
<div id="text"></div>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li movieurl="jembe_3.ogv" data-text="text 1">Video 1</li>
    <li movieurl="jembe_4.ogv" data-text="text 2">Video 2</li>
    <li movieurl="jembe_5.ogv" data-text="text 3">Video 3</li>
    <li movieurl="jembe_6.ogv"  data-text="text 4">Video 4</li>
</ul>

<script src="jquery.min.js">; </script>
<script> 
    $(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
    $("#text").html($(this).data("text"));
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
        "autoplay": "autoplay"
    })
})

$("#videoarea").attr({
     "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl")
}) 

})
</script> 
</body>
```

if you want to add complex captions do like this:

```
<body>
<video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src=""></video>
<div id="text"></div>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li movieurl="jembe_3.ogv">
        Video 1
        <div class="caption">
            text 1 <br/>
            <b>text 2</b>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li movieurl="jembe_4.ogv">
        Video 2
        <div class="caption">
            text 1 <br/>
            <b>text 2</b>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li movieurl="jembe_5.ogv">
        Video 3
        <div class="caption">
            text 1 <br/>
            <b>text 2</b>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li movieurl="jembe_6.ogv">
        Video 4
        <div class="caption">
            text 1 <br/>
            <b>text 2</b>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script src="jquery.min.js">; </script>
<script> 
    $(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
    $("#text").html($(this).children(".caption").html());
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
        "autoplay": "autoplay"
    })
})

$("#videoarea").attr({
     "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl")
}) 

})
</script> 
</body>
```

Consider following rule in your css file:

```
#playlist .caption{display:none}
```

Comment: Yes this solution works. Just if I want to ad more text then only a legend the handling becomes difficult.

Comment: And Yes again, your second section is overseeable and why not write the text in the html section. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The relevant parts,

```
<ul id="playlist">
    <li movieurl="jembe_3.ogv" videotext="here some text to video1">Video 1</li>
    <li movieurl="jembe_4.ogv" videotext="some other text to video2">Video 2</li>
</ul>


$("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
  $("#videoarea").attr({
      "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
      "autoplay": "autoplay"
  })
  $("#videotext").text($(this).attr("videotext"));
})


$("#videoarea").attr({
     "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl")
})
$("#videotext").text($("$playlist li").eq(0).attr("videotext"));
```

As best practice you'd probably want to use `data-movieurl` and `data-movietext`.

EDIT, to keep the text in separate files:

```
<ul id="playlist">
    <li movieurl="jembe_3.ogv" fileurl="file1.html">Video 1</li>
    <li movieurl="jembe_4.ogv" fileurl="file2.html">Video 2</li>
</ul>

$("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
  $("#videoarea").attr({
      "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
      "autoplay": "autoplay"
  })
  $("#videotext").load($(this).attr("fileurl"));
})
```

Comment: Yes this solution works. Just if I want to ad more text then only a legend the handling becomes difficult.

Comment: If you prefer to keep the text in separate files the you can grab the text using `.load` http://api.jquery.com/load/ with the file name as an attribute of the `li`

Answer (score 0):

You could store your information in json format, how you load this information is another entirely different topic I'm not going to go into.

You would have a JSON file which contained the following:

```
{
  "movie_data": [
    {
      "id":"movie1",
      "title":"some movie"
    },
    {
      "id":"movie2",
      "title":"some other movie"
    }
  ]
}
```

You could use `JSON.parse` to retrieve the contents above into an Object, and using a similar method of data attributes you could use the `id` value within each of the objects withing `movie-data` to match that to the data attribute.

```
<ul>
    <li movieurl="jembe_3.ogv" data-movie-text="movie1">Video 1</li>
    <li movieurl="jembe_4.ogv" data-movie-text="movie2">Video 2</li>
</ul>
```

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ecsyfj4y/